# How to get product of all elements in a row of matrix in Julia

Tags: matrix, julia

I'm using Julia and trying to get a vector p. The elements of p is the multiplying product of all elements in the same row of matrix P. I can do it by using for loops on each row, but is there a more efficient way to do it?

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you add a copy-pastable minimal code example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: There are several ways of doing this, but loops are at least as efficient as the other methods. In most cases, loops provide optimal performance in Julia.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Answers below solve my problem nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you should be able to do

```
julia> P = reshape(1:9, 3, 3)
3×3 reshape(::UnitRange{Int64}, 3, 3) with eltype Int64:
 1  4  7
 2  5  8
 3  6  9

julia> prod.(eachrow(P))
3-element Vector{Int64}:
  28
  80
 162
```

Comment: or `vec(prod(P, dims=2))`.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you both of you!

Comment: `map(prod,eachrow(m))`